# Can I loot other Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary doors?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim I destroyed the Dark Brotherhood; can I get into the other sanctuary doors (without being in the Brotherhood) and loot them?

Comment: Have you tried it? I've wondered the same thing myself. If the password isn't the same, I don't believe you can.

Answer (score 1):

The normal answer would be no. But there is one way that works most of the time. Disable and enable the Door of the sanctuary and unlock it all using console commands and if done right, it should open up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on PC, you can teleport to the interior of the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary with this console command:

`coc DarkBrotherhoodSanctuary`

Answer (score -1):

No you cant, the Dawnstar santuary door will ask what is the music of life but your character will clueless of what that means. To do so, go to Arentino residence  and then kill Grelod in Riften Honor Hall then go to sleep and then Astrid will tell you.

Comment: This seriously needs some punctuation.